# Question about norm convergence in quotient spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed spaces, $U\subseteq X$ a closed subspace.

> Is it true that, if $\bar{x}_n \rightarrow \bar{x}$ in $X/U$, then I can find $u_n \in U$ with $x_n+u_n\rightarrow x$?

For some context, I'm trying to show that the index is a continuous map from the multiplicative group of the Calkin algebra of $X$ (plus some other hypothesis).

*My try*: $\overline{x_n-x}\rightarrow 0$, so that $\inf_{u \in U}||x_n-x+u||\rightarrow _n 0$. By picking $u_n$ at each step so that $||x_n-x+u_n||$ is small enough (thanks to the infimum properties) one should be able to get the claim. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, you are almost there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's denote the quotient map by $\pi:X\to X/U$. So we have a sequence $(x_n)\subset X$ and a point $x\in X$ so that $\pi(x_n)\to\pi(x)$. Equivalently, $\pi(x_n-x)\to0$, so without loss of generality we can assume that $x=0$ and thus $\pi(x_n)\to0$. Now for any point $z\in X$ we have that
$$\|\pi(z)\|=\inf_{u\in U}\|z+u\|$$
by definition. So for each $n\geq1$, by the elementary properties of the infimum, you can choose $u_n\in U$ so that $\|x_n+u_n\|\leq\|\pi(x_n)\|+\frac{1}{n}$. But now $\|\pi(x_n)\|\to0$ since $\pi(x_n)\to0$, so the right hand side of the inequality converges to $0$, so $\|x_n+u_n\|\to0$, i.e. $x_n+u_n\to0$.